# Express JS next('route')

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I just learned that this is the way to try another route. Say for example you have a scenario where you have 3 'get' routes

```
app.get('/:customparam1', custom1);
app.get('/:customparam2', custom2);
app.get('/:customparam3', custom3);
```

And we have for each method something like:

```
custom# = function(req, res, next) {
  req.collections.findOne({req.params}, function(err, coll) {
    // do stuff here 
  })
}
```

My question is, does express try the routes in the order they are listed? If that is the case then, would I be correct in saying we want to write next('route') in custom1 and and custom2 route methods but not in custom3 since that would be the final route that is checked?

The assumption would be that if we don't find a match by the final route then there is a programmer error somewhere.

Comment: You are correct. Like middleware, routes are executed in the order they are defined.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much but just wanted to be sure.